# Change/update Zoo Visitor entry expiration date after order submitted

Tags: expresso-store, zoo-visitor, expresso

I'm trying to find a way to update a Zoo Visitor member entry expiration date after an order in Store has been placed/confirmed.

The order is a subscription renewal so the member/member details already exist in the database.

I am capturing a new expiration date (set to one year ahead) as a custom field when taking the order.

I just don't know how to update the members entry with the new expiration date?

Appreciate any ideas/help.

Comment: You need to craft an extension that hits a hook from your store addon. When you get a renewal submit, you do a channel entries api update (our just pure MySQL update). Read the ExpressionEngine addon development guides: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html I can probably provide an example if you can't suss it out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm reading through the extension docs but as a front-end developer I'm still pretty lost. If you have time to put a basic example together, that would be a great help.

Comment: If no one helps you out before tonight (I'm in Massachusetts, US), I will. I was late to work and can't be screwing around on the forums during work today.